# Escape single quote mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have the following query:

```
$query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items 
          SET extra_fields=\''.$campos_extra_updated.'\' 
          WHERE id='.$item_id;
```

`$campos_extra_updated` contains the following value which I was able to retreive with a different query before trying to escape the quotes:

```
UPDATE ikyfb_k2_items SET extra_fields = "[{"id":"2","value":"Ser mayor de edad"},
{"id":"3","value":"asdf"},{"id":"4","value":9999998},{"id":"5","value":"10"},
{"id":"6","value":"7"},{"id":"7","value":"3"},{"id":"8","value":"1"},
{"id":"9","value":"2014-05-28"},{"id":"10","value":"2014-05-30"},
{"id":"11","value":"2014-05-28"},{"id":"12","value":"2014-05-31"},{"id":"14","value":"25"},{"id":"15","value":"20"},{"id":"16","value":"Consigue descuento ahora!"},
{"id":"17","value":"123abc"}]" WHERE id=52
```

After the `SET extra_fields =` and at the end of `{"id":"17","value":"123abc"}]` the double apostrophe should be single quotes for the query to work.

What am I doing wrong? I have also tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Not using [prepared queries](http://php.net/pdo), for one...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what do you mean prepared queries?

Comment: And that `$query` var is not generating that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the following:

```
$query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items 
          SET extra_fields=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($campos_extra_updated).'\' 
          WHERE id='.$item_id;
```

Comment: What are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`? You should be using Joomla's API

Comment: @Lodder I looked around and couldnt find anything, could you please let me know which Joomla API?

Comment: Use JDatabase and JDatabaseQuery.